# How does 'notwithstanding' mean 'in spite of'?

Tags: etymology

> [notwithstanding](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/notwithstanding) =  {preposition} In spite of
>   {adverb} = Nevertheless; in spite of this:
>
> [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=notwithstanding&searchmode=none): late 14c., *notwiþstondynge,* from **not** + present participle of the verb **withstand**.
>   A loan-translation of Medieval Latin *non obstante* "being no hindrance," from ablative of *obstans*, present participle of *obstare* "stand opposite to" (see [obstacle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=obstacle&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>   As an adverb and as a conjunction from early 15c.
>
> [`withstand`](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/withstand)  = [with object]
>   1. Remain undamaged or unaffected by; `resisting` :

How can I understand 'not**withstand**ing',  only by thinking in terms of the root **withstand**?
I try to rewrite not**withstand**ing below. Did I guess the right definition of **withstand**  above?

1. Notwithstanding X, Y happens.
2. = NOT withstanding X, Y happens.
3. = Failing to withstand X, Y happens.
(In 3,  Y is suppressed in the adjunct. Expand it as: Y, failing to withstand X, Y happens.)

Comment: 'Notwithstanding X' or using postpositionally 'X notwithstanding' means 'X not proving to be an insuperable hindrance'. It's X that doesn't withstand. But with 'Withstanding X ...', it's Y that's overcoming or withstanding X. This is using agent terminology; it may not always be appropriate, but the principle will still hold.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for that. It is one I have often pondered. It is far clearer when you say 'X notwithstanding'. It does render 'notwithstanding X' a bit nonsensical, doesn't it?

Comment: @Law, your series of substitutions turned notwithstanding on its head. 3. should read "X UN-successfully resisting, Y happened." X is not the object of "withstand"; it is the subject .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP definition of *withstand* is correct, but it has a *passive construction* that visually ***confuses*** the 4-sentence formulation. In all four of the OP sentences, the meaning is correct:

### **Y happens *in spite of* X**

but the 4 sentences have created an ***optical illusion***, because the meaning of the sentences is **not** tabulated in columns as the OP erroneously assumes.

I propose the following syllogism to ***avoid*** confusing *withstand*  and *notwithstanding*:

> **Y** is happening;
>
> **X** cannot resist sufficiently;
>
> ***Therefore*, Y happens!**

---

We have several different formulas to **express** that logical outcome using the word *notwithstanding*, and each one can be tested for accuracy:

- As a **[preposition](http://grammarist.com/usage/notwithstanding/):** "In spite of **X**, **Y** happens," yielding a real-life use of *notwithstanding*:

> *Notwithstanding* **Harry's insults**, I will **smile**.
>
> My smile (**Y**) is happening...Harry's insults (**X**) cannot resist
> sufficiently...*therefore*, my smile happens!

---

- As a **[postpositional preposition](http://grammarist.com/usage/notwithstanding/)**: "**X** not *withstanding*, **Y** happens," yielding a real-life use of *notwithstanding* :

> **Weather** *notwithstanding*, the **parade** will happen.
>
> The parade (**Y**) is happening...the weather (**X**) cannot resist sufficiently...*Therefore*, the parade happens!

---

- As an **[adverb](http://grammarist.com/usage/notwithstanding/)**: "**X** happens, *nevertheless*, **Y** happens," yielding a real-life use of *notwithstanding*:

> "**Jesse cried**; *notwithstanding*, the **policeman** wrote the citation."
>
> The policeman (**Y**) is writing the citation...Jesse crying (**X**) cannot resist sufficiently...*therefore*, the policeman writes the citation!

We can transpose the word order of an adverbial *notwithstanding* with precisely the same meaning.

> "**Jesse cried**; the **policeman** wrote the citation *notwithstanding.*"
>
> The policeman (**Y**) is writing the citation...Jesse crying (**X**) cannot resist sufficiently...*therefore*, the policeman writes the citation!

---

**Conclusion**:

The general meaning of *notwithstanding* is always:

### **Y happens *in spite of* X**

even when the word order prevents that specific phrasing.

If you absolutely insist on thinking of it in terms of *'withstand'* then it is simply,

Y withstands X

, and either of the definitions for *'withstand'* can be inserted.

NB: Does it seem like *notwithstanding* is approaching its natural lexical death?
http://grammarist.com/usage/notwithstanding/

---

Comment: There probably is a streamline.

Comment: Thanks. After rereading your superlative answer, I wonder if your conclusion should instead be: X canNOT withstand Y = Notwithstanding X, Y. Your present conclusion is: `Y withstands X`, but where's the **NOT** in **NOTwithstanding**?

Comment: It is a win/lose scenario. Y withstands (successfully resists) X, because X can**not** withstand (successfully resist) Y. The Patriots beat the Seahawks, because the Seahawks could not beat the Patriots. The Seahawks notwithstanding, the Patriots won.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for only returning to this now, but would you like to integrate your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

*notwithstanding* and *in spite of* call for a noun-phrase (e.g. "its illegality")

> Moonshine thrives in the Appalachians, its illegality notwithstanding.
>   Its illegality notwithstanding, moonshine thrives in the Appalachians.
>   Moonshine thrives in the Appalachians in spite of its illegality.
>   In spite of its illegality, moonshine thrives in the Appalachians.

whereas *nevertheless* calls for a predicate-phrase (e.g. *though [it be]|although it is illegal*).

> Moonshine, though illegal, nevertheless thrives in the Appalachians.
>   Moonshine, though illegal, thrives in the Appalachians nevertheless.
>   Moonshine, although it is illegal, nevertheless thrives in the Appalachians.
>   Moonshine, although it is illegal, thrives in the Appalachians nevertheless.

Comment: Elegant attempt, but I'm afraid I don't quite understand. I specifically don't see how *though illegal* can possibly be a 'predicate'. Indeed the verb *thrive* is intransitive, so there cannot therefore, by definition, be a predicate. *Though illegal* and *although it is illegal* are adjectival clauses. Perhaps that is what you meant?

Comment: Would "predication" be clearer?

Comment: 'Predication' has essentially the same meaning as 'predicate'. Besides I have never heard of the former being used to describe any feature of grammar. I have learned one thing from this, however, and that is that an intransitive can have a 'predicate'. The latter is 'anything that states something about a subject'. In your example, however, that would be 'thrives in the Appalachian mountains', not 'although it is illegal'.

Comment: The intransitivity of *thrives* has nothing to do with the relationship of *nevertheless* to the relevant clause. I am trying to describe that relevant clause as a form of assertion, as distinct from the noun-phrase that *notwithstanding* requires.

Comment: I'd call it an adjectival clause. But I'm no authority on grammar, just a humble native speaker.

Comment: A predicate adjective?

Comment: No I wouldn't call it that, because it doesn't qualify the predicate, it qualifies the subject of the sentence. Why don't we just call it an 'although clause'. It seems as if an 'although' is needed, or at least a suggestion of one, in order to bring in 'nevertheless'.

Comment: It seems the distinction @TRomano is trying to make is the **function** of the two words! *Nevertheless* is almost always used as an adverb (I only hesitate to say always because we are discussing **English** :). *Notwithstanding* can be used as a preposition, OR an adverb, OR a conjunction. I'm not sure how cogent that distinction to the question.

Comment: @ScotM: Thanks. I direct this comment to user TRomano too. Sorry, but I don't understand the relation between your answer and my OP. Does this answer only discuss the position of words?

Comment: The reply is an attempt to answer your question ('How does 'notwithstanding' mean 'in spite of'?) by showing the word used in sentences where it has that meaning: *in spite of the laws prohibiting production and sale of home-made liquor, moonshine thrives*. That is, those laws are no real hindrance to the sale and production of moonshine. Moonshine thrives, despite them.