# Feel Good but Meaningless Phrase

Tags: single-word-requests, descriptive-grammar

I am looking for a word that describes general phrases that makes one feel good but has no real meaning, such as, "I'm for tolerance."  Well, maybe in some things you are but in others you aren't (murder).  This is just a "______."

Comment: Where does the word  'murder' fit into this question?

Comment: Clichés that are over-simplified and that nobody disagrees with are labelled   "mother, love and apple-pie."

Comment: A *political speech*?

Comment: @chasly I’m guessing it’s a comment to people who say platitudes like “I’m for tolerance!” as absolute truths. Most are probably not very much for tolerance when it comes to something like murder.

Comment: *This is just an **axiom***--it's so obviously true that rationally oriented people feel like it doesn't need to be said, but emotionally oriented people prefer to reinforce the obvious truth with an explicit statement. [Duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222502/is-there-a-word-that-describes-a-statement-whose-negative-is-senseless-or-would) and driven by subjective opinions.

Answer (score 5):

**platitude**

> A remark or statement, especially one with a moral content, that has been used too often to be interesting or thoughtful:
> ‘she began uttering liberal platitudes’
>
> *[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/platitude)*

cliché

truism

commonplace

Comment: Putting the name of the dictionary in text with a link to the site makes it easier for readers to recognize the source.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps rhetoric is the word your looking for.  Or maybe 'mere rhetoric'.

> b. Language that is elaborate, pretentious, insincere, or intellectually vacuous: His offers of compromise were mere rhetoric.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rhetoric