# What is an advanced vocabulary word to replace "truth"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Truth as in a fact or a belief by the church.

Comment: You need to explain in much more detail the context you use the word in.

Comment: Also, what did a thesaurus suggest and why did none of those fit for what you want?

Comment: Why "religious truth" doesn't fit ? Are you looking for **orhtodoxia**, **faith**, **revelation**, **doctrine** or something else ? Please clarify your request.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a ***tenet***,
Defined in Merriam Webster’s Collegiate Dictionary as

> a principle, belief, or doctrine generally held to be true; esp: one held in common by members of an organization, movement, or profession

Answer (score 2):

Is it a fact or just a belief?

**Verity**: something that is objectively true, whether anyone believes it or not. "Triangles have three sides"

**Tenet**: a belief held but that may not be true. "All people should wear underwear on the outside of their clothes"

**Dogma**: a tenet asserted as a verity. "Athena sprang full-grown and fully-armed from the head of Zeus"

Answer (score 1):

My favourite is [***axiom***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/axiom):

> 1 : a maxim widely accepted on its intrinsic merit
>   2 : a statement accepted as true as the basis for argument or inference
>   3 : an established rule or principle or a self-evident truth

[Merriam Webster]

I believe it hovers nicely between truths that are postulated, and truth that are experienced.

An interesting discussion of the shades of the meaning of this word can be found in answers to  [this question at EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222502/is-there-a-word-that-describes-a-statement-whose-negative-is-senseless-or-would).