# How does 'X notwithstanding' = 'notwithstanding X'?

Tags: differences, adverbs

Please explain 'notwithstanding', only in terms of the adverb 'not' and the root verb 'withstand'.

> [ [Grammarist:](http://grammarist.com/usage/notwithstanding/) ] ***Notwithstanding*** is mainly a [preposition](http://grammarist.com/grammar/prepositions/) meaning *in spite of*. Most dictionaries also list it as an [adverb](http://grammarist.com/grammar/adverbs/) meaning *nevertheless,* but this sense is rarely used in modern English. *Notwithstanding* is always one word, and this has been the standard spelling for many centuries.
>
> Although *notwithstanding* usually means exactly the same as *in spite of*, it is often positioned differently. *In spite of* always comes before its object—e.g., “In spite of your feedback, I’m not changing anything.” **But *notwithstanding* is often postpositive, meaning it comes after its object**—e.g., “Your feedback notwithstanding, I’m not changing anything.” **Of course, it can come before its object as well**—e.g., “Notwithstanding your feedback, I’m not changing anything.”

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/216438/50720) substantiates the quote overhead, and explains that:

1. **Notwithstanding** X, Y (happens).
2. = X **notwithstanding**, Y.
3. = X **canNOT withstand** Y.

But why don't 1 and 2 differ in signification? Why doesn't the position of 'notwithstanding' affect its signification?

Comment: 1. *notwithstanding* has an existence, meaning and usage of its own, its etymology notwithstanding.

Comment: 2. *notwithstanding* is associated with Y in both instances (5, 6) whatsa prob then?

Comment: 3. "X happens, nevertheless, Y happens." may be syntactically valid but fails to make unambiguous sense to me.

Comment: We also have [linguistics.se] a few blocks from ELU.

Comment: @Kris Thank you! I had forgotten about it until your recommendation. I enlarge the scope of this question to include « nonobstant » in French: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/11550/5306

Comment: Law, as Kris has explained, it is utterly commonplace in English that English is "illogical".  Your question is literally identical in tenor to asking "why is fish not spelled phish?"  The only real answer is "So what?"  It's just a **matter of common usage**, there's nothing else.  Sure, you can ask "why historically" do e have color or colour, but really "who cares"?

Comment: As [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/notwithstanding) says, 'notwithstanding' also exists as a **postposition**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appearance and behavior of *notwithstanding* are pretty odd—and they seem odder the more you look at the word. In the first place, *withstand* doesn't mean, as you might suppose from adding *with* to *stand*, "stand with," but rather "stand against." In this respect, the *with-* component functions like the *with-* in *withdraw* ("draw against") or in *withhold* ("hold against"), and not like the *with-* in *withal* ("together with").

The *not-* component makes sense in constructions of the type "Y is true, X notwithstanding," where we can infer that the sense is "Y is true, and under scrutiny X does not stand against it." But when we flip the construction around to say "Y is true, notwithstanding X," it is easy (albeit erroneous) to imagine that the statement logically means "Y is true, and under scrutiny it does not stand against X"—which doesn't make sense if X and Y tend in opposite directions.

What's going on here? Let's pick up the thread from Bryan Garner, [*Garner's Modern American Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FwmQpyibKkAC&pg=PA575&dq=%22notwithstanding+is+a+FORMAL+WORD%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rA0mVeWRF8b7oQSJ2oHACA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22notwithstanding%20is%20a%20FORMAL%20WORD%22&f=false), third edition (2009):

> **notwithstanding** is a FORMAL WORD, used in the sense "despite," "in spite of," or "although." E.g., "*Notwithstanding* an outpouring of editorial opinion on either side of this issue, there are no easy answers." [Citation omitted.]
>
> The question that literalists ask [about *notwithstanding*] is, What doesn't withstand what else? Is the outpouring of opinion "not withstanding" (i.e., subordinated to) the lack of easy answers, or is the lack of easy answers "not withstanding" (subordinated to) the outpouring of editorial opinion? Because the former is the correct reading, some believe that *notwithstanding* should be sent to the end of the phrase in which it appears: *The family's objection to the marriage notwithstanding*, as opposed to *Notwithstanding the family's objection to the marriage*.
>
> But the literalist argument is very much in vain, as the OED attests with a 14th-century example of notwithstanding as a sentence starter. This usage has been constant since from the 1300s to the present day. In fact, the construction with **notwithstanding** following the noun first appeared more than a century later, and has never been as frequent. ...

Ernest Weekley, *An Etymological Dictionary of Modern English*, volume 2 (1921), at [page 993 of the book itself (but page 497 of the online viewer with the scroller at the bottom)](https://archive.org/stream/etymologicaldict00weekuoft#page/496/mode/2up), offers this brief account:

> **notwithstanding.** From *not* and *withstand*, to oppose, the word now app[ears] governed by the prep[osition] being really the subject of the verb, e.g. *notwithstanding this* is "this is not opposing." Cf. archaic F[rench] *nonobstant*, L[atin] *non obstante* (abl[ative] absolute).
> [Early example:] Not that withstanding she ansuered in this manere
> ([cited in] *N[ew] E[nglish] D[ictionary*, Oxford, 1884] ca. 1500).

And finally, Wilfred Funk, *Word Origins* (1950) has this:

> When a man finds himself faced with a lot of stubborn obstacles in some business project, he will occasionally make a decision that *nevertheless* and *notwithstanding* these handicaps he is still going ahead. At one time the word *with* meant "against," and so our entrepreneur is going to take his gamble *notwithstanding*, or, in other words, "no matter what stands against him."

So both "notwithstanding X" and "X notwithstanding" mean "in spite of X"; within that clause, *notwithstanding* is position-independent and aligns against X regardless of which element comes first in the clause. If that seems confusing, imagine how a person in medieval England would have felt if told by a dangerous-looking armed man, "You're either with us or against us!"

Comment: +1. Thanks. 1. The following concerns the last sentence of your 2nd para: Would you please clarify your meaning of `which doesn't make sense if X and Y tend in opposite directions`? I've seen 'tend to/towards', but not 'tend IN'? 2. Also, I don't understand the metaphor in the last sentence. Please explain?

Comment: 2. Also, I don't understand the metaphor in the last sentence. Please explain?

Comment: 3. Sorry for this quantity, but in your 4th last para, what's the antecedent of 'this word' in `From not and withstand, to oppose, the word` ?

Comment: 1. My point here is that it doesn't make sense to say that Y is true and yet to say that it doesn't stand up to X, if X runs counter to Y—that is if X denies the validity of Y either directly or by implication ("tendency"). 2. The last line imagines a time when, as Wilfred Funk says in the last quote "the word _with_ meant 'against'." In that case, if someone said "you're either with us or against us," the statement would amount to saying "you're either against us or against us"—not something you'd want to hear from dangerous-looking armed men. (It's a word-play joke, you see). ...

Comment: ... 3. In Weekley's quote, "From _not_ and _withstand_, to oppose, the word now app[ears] ..." the words "to oppose" define _withstand_, which appears one word earlier in the sentence; "the word" refers to _notwithstanding_, which is the bolded entry header immediately preceding the sentence in question.

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively for your support and quick replies. I am sorry for forgetting to ask this earlier, but would you like to integrate your comments into your answer?

Comment: Sorry if you mind my minor edits, but I thought to identify the page numbers also.