# How does 'going forth with others' semantically shift to mean 'going at the same as they do'?

Tags: etymology

Can someone please expound 'the process of transition' (from [this explanation](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-for2.htm)) that I pinpointed with a red arrow below?  The website doesn't detail how " this sense of time eventually took over". Can someone please speculate or detail "the process of transition"?

> It seems this sense of time eventually took over, though the process of transition isn’t very clear, and it’s mixed up with other phrases that also referred to time.
>
> [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did 'forthwith' evolve to mean 'immediately'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250526/how-did-forthwith-evolve-to-mean-immediately)

Comment: @HotLicks No. I was aware of that question when I posted this one. This question focusses on a few sentences that website failed to expound.

Comment: _How does 'going forth with others and at the same time as they' semantically shift to mean 'immediately'?_ It doesn't. You've misunderstood that sentence. _If you **go forth with others**, you must necessarily **go at the same time as they do**._

Comment: Over time, the word Forthwith changed to mean something separate from Forth and With. That is the transition.