# How did 'against the outside' (without) evolve to mean 'outside'?

Tags: etymology, old-english

> [without (adv., prep.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=without&searchmode=none) [<--]
>       Old English *wiðutan* "outside of, from outside," literally "**against** the outside" (opposite of *within*), see [***with***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=with&allowed_in_frame=0) + [out](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=out&allowed_in_frame=0) (adv.). [...]

I am guessing that here, the prefix ***with-*** means **against**, per the foregoing  and [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/238307/50720). However, if something is "**against** the outside", then it must be the opposite of 'outside': ie, INside or withIN. But then  this is a contradiction. So where did I err in interpreting  the dead metaphor?

Please expose and explain all this etymology's (hidden and missing) semantic drifts and links. What is a right way of interpreting the etymology, to understand how the semantic jumps abstracted and severed from the original literal meaning? What bridges the jumps with the original meaning?

Comment: Bjr, "against the outside" simply means "leaning against the outside".  Imagine you're in a walled city. Something is outside, but hard against the wall .. leaning against the outside. It's that simple.

Comment: Are you sure in `against the outside` against is a negation? A ladder leans against the outside of the house. They hold against each other....

Comment: @JoeBlow Almost at the same time... :-)

Comment: As Daniel says, "against" meaning nothing more than "leaning against" "touching" .. contre le mur, you know?  it's that simple

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks. I think that I misinterpreted 'against' then. I wonder why though...

Comment: Le P.  Your final paragraph is basically meaningless  :)  There is nothing, whatsoever, to expose etc. I think you just were not aware that "against" means "leaning against", "touching".  Imagine two books in a bookshelf - you could say "one is against the other" .. it just means "touching", "contre"

Comment: Le P.  If you misinterpreted "against" it's probably because you're not a native speaker :)  I misinterpret a cote all the time, and I don't even know where to put the fucking accents!

Comment: "With" -> against = facing towards.  Consider "to withstand an enemy"

Comment: @LePressentiment I used a different style to make it clear. I will repeat it, in a different fashion. "Are you sure in **`against the outside`** the word against is a negation?"

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. I did interpret `against` there as a negation, but my interpretation was wrong.

Comment: Hi Le P. ... "against the outside..." is absolutely normal and commonplace.  "I am leaning against the outside of the house".  You ask about "negation".  There is utterly no involvement, whatsoever, with "negation".  Against means nothing more than "touching" or "leaning into".  Look in dictionary,

Comment: "I did interpret against there as a negation, but my interpretation was wrong"  Yes, there is utterly no relationship to negation.  it just means "leaning" :)   l'échelle est appuyée sur le mur, the ladder is against the wall.

Comment: I think he can be excused his misunderstanding, since the first definition of _against_ is _in opposition to_, as in _fighting against an enemy_.

Answer (score 0):

Purely FTR,

"against" here simply means, basically "touching", "leaning against".

(Nothing more than as in "I am leaning against a wall".)

This decompresses all seeming mysteries sought in the OP.

Comment: +1. Thanks again. To clarify, is 'leaning against the outside' truly the `opposite of within` (as claimed by Etymonline in my OP)? Leaning against the outside of the wall, a ladder can be used to access the 'inside'. So how did `"(leaning) against the outside"` evolve into `"outside of, from outside," `?

Comment: Your comments completely confuse me.  (1) the "online dictionary" you mention has a definition for **without**.  it mentions (for some reason) the opposite of **without** is **within**.  so what?  (2) secondly in explaining "without" it suggest the sentence fragment "leaning against the outside".  You are trying to "link" these two facts.  there is no link, the question exists only in your head.  the concept: "'leaning against the outside' is the opposite of within" is a meaningless collection of words. No matter how many times you type it, I am afraid it means **nothing**. (Cont...)

Comment: To repeat, if you type "'leaning against the outside' is the opposite of within" "'leaning against the outside' is the opposite of within" "'leaning against the outside' is the opposite of within" again and again, I'm afraid it remains totally meaningless.  If you then "ask a question" about this ("how did it evolve"), that is an utterly meaningless concept, you are asking a question about a meaningless, random collection of words.  I'm sorry.

Comment: 1. From your answer, "against the outside" = 'leaning against the outside.' 2. Etymonline above claims that 1 = 'opposite of within'. 3. So I'm asking how 1 relates to 2. Clear now?

Comment: Hi LeP.  Are you basically addressing the microscopic difference between "outside the castle in general" (just "outside") and "outside ........ leaning against the wall".  Is that what you're getting at?  if so there is very little to say, words always have many different extremely subtle variations.  BTW note that "outside (the castle)" can imply "just" outside (say, within some meters...) ... "She's outside the gate!"  Or it can imply, well, the entire say "region" ("the battalion are outside somewhere").  Or it can mean "the fields outside" (say ... within 1-2 km).

Comment: Next, you mention that "Etymonline" (a rubbish reference, but whatever...) mentions that one meaning of "without" is "opposite of within".  So ... what is your question? So what?  Yes, one meaning of "without" is "opposite of within".  There are many meanings of "without" and there are **many ways a dictionary writer could express those** sundry meanings.

Comment: Hence, **"So I'm asking how 1 relates to 2"**  the only relationship is this: the word you typed in "1" happened to appear somewhere in some tract about "without", and, the words you typed in "2" also happened to appear somewhere in some tract about "without".  It is difficult to understand why there should be any connection at all between these two "random thoughts," as it were, about the word "without".

Comment: Everyone has already mentioned, many times, that "against" (as in "against a wall") simply means "leaning against."  (It has utterly nothing or do with, no connection to, "contra" , as in say "I am against the DomTom getting my money" or "I am against long comments on this site.")

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Yes, I was confused by the `the microscopic difference between "outside the castle in general" (just "outside") and "outside ........ leaning against the wall"`. Outside something in general, implies the state of truly being outside. However, `outside ........ leaning against the wall` implies some interest in whatever's INSIDE or WITHIN the wall. (eg If you lean a ladder against the outside, you intend to enter WITHIN). So I'm struggling to connect `outside ........ leaning against the wall` with just 'outside'. Did I clarify?

Comment: Hi LeP.  you say "leaning against a wall" *"implies some interest in whatever's INSIDE or WITHIN the wall"*.  I simply cannot see that at all.  It could refer to say a criminal "leaning against the wall" or just something that happens to be leaning against the wall.  But the bigger point is, the difference between those two shades of meaning **is microscopic**.  "blue" and "without" mean very different things.  the two shades of meaning you mention of "without" are microscopically different.  Again, you say **So I'm asking how 1 relates to 2.** but what do you mean? how would it "relate"?...

Comment: for any given word (say "blue") there are 1000 microscopically different meanings.  So what?

Comment: Thanks again for the continued help. I can't pinpoint why, but somehow, to me, `leaning against` (something that separates the inside from the outside), still relates to the inside, because you're `leaning against` something that contains the inside. So I don't interpret `leaning against the outside` as completely outside. Does this clarify?

Comment: Hi LeP!  I'm afraid that really I am unable to explain what I am saying. You are making far too much of the "leaning against" aspect. IT was just one passing text in one dictionary. And again the differences you mention are microscopic. Words have various shades like that. Sorry I can't explain better. Cheers